# Multiple protocol EMAIL client (browser based, using javascript/jQuery and LAMP)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, lamp

I am an ubuntu user and very much fascinated by **evolution** mail client. I want to write a similar code for **browsers** using LAMP and jQuery/JavaScript.

I already have a table in mySQL with name as **user_account_details**. Where I have columns as userID, protocol, protocol_username, protocol_password.

I don't need the complete code. I only want someone to show me the correct direction. I don't have any idea how to do this. And how these multiple protocol Email clients works.

**Modification: I am only worried about yahoo, gmail, hotmail, and rediffmail as protocols for now.**

***Any reference LINK would be a great help...***

Thanks

Comment: first, set your terminology right. yahoo, gmail, hotmail, and rediffmail are NOT protocols!

Answer (score 0):

This endeavor shouldn't be taken lightly. And you're still only at the front end. But here are some links for the back end.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

For the front end, here's a primer:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent

Comment: I forgot to mention that, in my case, I want only gmail and yahoo emails. No other protocols. If possible, will add rediffmail and hotmail too, but LATER. Few minutes back I came across the yahoo mail API, its awesome. I want something like that for gmail and hotmail too.. Ok.. So what is your answer now?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is google broken again?

gmail uses pop/imap for retrievning - so the standard libs will work, but IIRC, SMTP requires authentication.

[This class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5375-PHP-Mass-Send-Attach-Embed-Through-SMTP-or-MAIL-.html) implements sending mail via gmail, hotmail and yahoo

[This one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5438-PHP-Import-contacts-from-Web-mail-accounts.html) imports contacts from various webmail services

[Hail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hail/) is a complete hotmail client written in PHP

A quick browse around the internet suggests that hotmail and yahoo have both been providing POP access for some time.

Do have a look at [squirrelmail](http://squirrelmail.org/) - its a very good web-based MUA written in PHP